# install and run kubeadm in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubeadm

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I am newbie k8s.

I am following this official document. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install -y docker.io
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
# curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
# cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
# apt-get update
# apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
# docker info | grep -i cgroup
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Here's no problem.

But in "Configure cgroup driver used by kubelet on Master Node" section,

in my 10-kubeadm.conf file,
there's no cgroup message so I can't use sed command.
`sed -i "s/cgroup-driver=systemd/cgroup-driver=cgroupfs/g" /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS=--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true"
Environment="KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS=--network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin"
Environment="KUBELET_DNS_ARGS=--cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
Environment="KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS=--authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
Environment="KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS=--cadvisor-port=0"
Environment="KUBELET_CERTIFICATE_ARGS=--rotate-certificates=true --cert-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/pki"
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS $KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS $KUBELET_CERTIFICATE_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

Should I add `Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"` line in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to add that option to your configuration if you don't have it in the configuration file.

That is optional parameter. Just make sure that if it is exists, it is a same with `Cgroup Driver` of Docker.